# Joomla form variable handling

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

I have a situation where I need to create a shortcut for a specific filter in a Joomla component.

The problem is that I cannot unset it, as I do not know if Joomla sets the form fields to its own session handler, request handler or some kind of custom handler. There also does not appear to be any documentation on this specific case.

The full situation is that I have a link that will auto filter in the same view as another link (in the components sidebar). One view will be just a specific filter and the other is standard. So I need it when you click into the filtered view it will reset the current filters to make sure everything displays as it should, and vice-versa so clicking back will again reset the filters.

I have tried a number of approaches for this, and although I can consistently force it to filter but it will not reset the form when I re-enter the last page with any technique I have tried so far and of course I want to avoid bypassing Joomla's default functions.

```
if(JRequest::getVar('filter_group_id',false)==10){
    JRequest::setVar('last_filter',true);
    EthicstoolHelper::addSubmenu('supervisors');
}else{
    if(JRequest::getVar('last_filter',false)===true){
        JRequest::setVar('last_filter',false);
        JRequest::setVar('filter_group_id',false)
    }
    EthicstoolHelper::addSubmenu('users');
}
```

This is the most recent think I have tried, as you can see I try to reset the value to false in a hope that Joomla will read it as not being set, as JRequest has no built in unset method.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I ran into a similar problem and couldn't solve it yet!

Comment: No, but my skills in Joomla have advanced to a point that I might be able to answer it, however not finding an answer led me to just scrapping the entire idea.... My guess now would be is to look at the components "states" built into the default classes, then when you call them in, do an override.

Comment: I see. I am definitely not at that point yet ;-)

Comment: There is a function called populateState in JModelLegacy that you could override, that would be my guess, try to use that to call in the filter and "reset" it. I will try to go into a more detailed answer when i got time :).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment yet, so I'm guessing a bit as to what the problem could be. Assuming that you are using a model to set the state of the filters, you can look at overriding the `populateState` method.

Another options is to fiddle with the `context` property in the model. For example, you could change the context if you have your special filters enabled if you are using things like `$app->getUserStateFromRequest()`. If you can post a bit more information about the design of your component (controllers and models), I can help more.